# Прослушивание сетевого трафика на C++ в Windows с обходом админ-прав

Tags: c++, winapi, сниффер

Задача - мониторинг приложением на C++ посещаемых сотрудниками интернет-ресурсов с последующей фильтрацией результатов и отправкой на сервер для фиксации этого в БД.
Нашёл в сети и отредактировал следующий код:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;
#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE 0x10000
#define SIO_RCVALL 0x98000001

char Buffer[MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; // 64 Kb

typedef struct IPHeader{
    unsigned char iph_verlen, iph_tos, iph_ttl, iph_protocol;     
    unsigned short iph_length, iph_id, iph_offset, iph_xsum;
    unsigned long iph_src, iph_dest;    
} IPHeader;

char src[10];
char dest[10];
char ds[15];
unsigned short lowbyte, hibyte;

int main(){
    WSADATA wsadata;   
    SOCKET Socket;         
    char name[128]; 
    HOSTENT* phe;       
    SOCKADDR_IN sa;       
    IN_ADDR sa1;       
    unsigned long flag = 1;  // Флаг PROMISC Вкл/выкл.

    // инициализация
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
    //cout << WSAGetLastError();
    gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
    phe = gethostbyname(name);
    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)phe->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
    bind(Socket, (SOCKADDR *)&sa, sizeof(SOCKADDR));

    ioctlsocket(Socket, SIO_RCVALL, &flag);

    while(true){
        int count = recv(Socket, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0);
        if (count >= sizeof(IPHeader)){
            IPHeader* hdr = (IPHeader *)Buffer;
            sa1.s_addr = hdr->iph_src;
            cout << "Src:";
            printf(inet_ntoa(sa1));
            cout<<endl;
            cout << "Dest:";
            sa1.s_addr = hdr->iph_dest;
            printf(inet_ntoa(sa1));
            cout << endl;
            switch(hdr->iph_protocol){
                case IPPROTO_TCP:
                    cout<<" TCP\n";
                    break;
                case IPPROTO_UDP:
                    cout<<" UDP\n";
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << " " <<(unsigned short)hdr->iph_protocol << endl;
                    break;
            }
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что из-под обычного пользователя ничего не логируется (одни 0.0.0.0 вместо IP) - реальные адреса показываются только при запуске приложения от имени администратора.

Мне не нужен полномасштабный снифер всея сети, - требуется лишь вшить в рабочий клиент функционал мониторинга сетевой активности текущего пользователя, который может работать и из-под гостя.

**Что в приведенном коде требует наличия прав администратора и можно ли это обойти?**

Comment: Скорее всего сырые сокеты

Comment: Очень много времени прошло) Но посоветую запустить службу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Права администратора требуются для использования raw сокетов. И это никак не обойти. Вот выдержка от Microsoft

> Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets
>   of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later

Comment: ОК, а без сырых сокетов можно организовать нечто подобное, хотя бы для исходящих запросов с ПК работника?